# MusiXTeX, two instruments with scalebox

Tags: musixtex, scalebox

I'm trying to write an extract of music with two instruments, and then resize it with a `scalebox` (I also tried with a `resizebox` and the problems are the sames).

First I tried:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

  \scalebox{1.0}{%
  \begin{music}%
    \instrumentnumber{2}%
    \setclef10%
    \setclef20%
    \nobarnumbers%
    \startextract%
      \notes \qa c & \qa d \en%
    \endextract%
  \end{music}%
  }

\end{document}
```

And I get this error when I compile:

```
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
<argument> ...numbers \startextract \notes \qa c &
                                                   \qa d \en \endextract \en...
l.17   }
```

Then I tried to put the music extract into a figure environment and then to scale it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

  \scalebox{1.0}{%
  \begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{music}%
      \instrumentnumber{2}%
      \setclef10%
      \setclef20%
      \nobarnumbers%
      \startextract%
        \notes \qa c & \qa d \en%
      \endextract%
    \end{music}%
  \end{figure}
  }

\end{document}
```

And I got this error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.
```

I, then, also tried to scale an extract with one instrument and two staffs, I did this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

  \scalebox{1.0}{
  \begin{music}
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setstaffs 1{2}
    \setclef{1}{00}
    \startextract
      \notes \qa c | \qa d \en
    \endextract
  \end{music}
  }

\end{document}
```

This compile, but It's doing this:

[image]

As we can see, instead of having a note on each staffs, both notes are on the bottom staff, and there is a pipe between the notes.

So, i there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do ?

Comment: That's an interesting observation. Even if one just puts the `music` environment in a savebox and uses it, the same issue arises.

Comment: This is not an answer, just a recommendation: MusiXTeX does a poor job and I really advise you to switch to LilyPond. While I love TeX, it's not a tool for music typesetting, which is very complex. If you plan to typeset more music, the sooner you switch the better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a full answer, but a workaround. With `xsavebox` you can rescale the notes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xsavebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{xlrbox}{mybox}%
\begin{music}
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setstaffs1{2}
    \setclef{1}{00}
    \startextract
      \notes \qa c | \qa d \en
    \endextract
  \end{music}%
\end{xlrbox}  


\fbox{\themybox}~\scalebox{0.6}{\themybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And one way to squeeze the very generous bounding box is to work with minipages.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xsavebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{xlrbox}{mybox}%
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
\begin{music}
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setstaffs1{2}
    \setclef{1}{00}
    \startextract
      \notes \qa c | \qa d \en
    \endextract
  \end{music}%
\end{minipage}%  
\end{xlrbox}  


\fbox{\themybox}~\scalebox{0.6}{\themybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And amazingly Ti*k*Z also works.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xsavebox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikz{\node[draw]{\begin{music}
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setstaffs1{2}
    \setclef{1}{00}
    \startextract
      \notes \qa c | \qa d \en
    \endextract
  \end{music}};}
~
\tikz{\node[draw,scale=0.6]{\begin{music}
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setstaffs1{2}
    \setclef{1}{00}
    \startextract
      \notes \qa c | \qa d \en
    \endextract
  \end{music}};}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I prefer the TikZ way, I find it more convenient. I just added `\hspace{-80pt}` to reduce the space on each sides. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Phantom If you go the Ti*k*Zy way, you could also work with a negative `inner xsep`, e.g. `\tikz{\node[draw,scale=0.6,inner xsep=-140pt]{\begin{music} .... `.

Comment: It does not really change the render, but it's simpler. Thanks